# Cocos2D HighScore framework

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i'm a new developer working on a game project using Cocos2D, I need help in integrating HighScore in my game, is there a good framework for this? or should i do it from scratch using TableView? i tried to find something related to this using google but all the topics were from 2009/10.

Please help!

Comment: try gamecenter leaderboard.(GameKit.framework)

Comment: you want it online shared or local?

Comment: I want it local for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel and cross-platform is not a concern, you can add a simple GameCenter leaderboard first (Apple provides a standard leaderboard view which your apps can use, you have to create the leaderboard on iTunes connect before implementing it).

Later, when you have the default version running, you can customize it to make it look like your game. You can read more about all this in the [Game Center Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

If on the other hand you want to avoid using Apple provided classes, see [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/137582-Mobile-Leaderboard-options-now-openfeint-is-gone) on the Unity forums where some alternatives are mentioned.

Comment: Why was this answer vote-down? mind mentioning reason before voting down??  thanks @rsanchezsaez for your answer!

Comment: I have accepted the answer as well as vote-up to get rid of negative score.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done high score implementation in Cocos2D game and i did something like following. Hope this helps.

(I have stored only top 5 high scores.)

1. Created HighScore.plist file with empty array (HighScoreArray) inside that.
2. In AppDelegate.m Copy HighScore.plist if its **not in** User Documents Directory.
3. When game is over you need to calculate and update HighScore.plist.

   - First of all check if current Score is not 0 (Zero).

     - Check if HighScore Array contains 5 scores.

       - YES then insert current score. Sort array and **remove last object** update plist.
       - NO then insert current score. Sort array and update plist file.